# Windows Virtual Smart Card (VSC) security error

Tags: javascript, certificate, windows-8.1, activexobject, capicom

Using javascript and activeX (CAPICOM Store api), I am trying to remove a certificate from the user Store through IE 11.

The javascript code I use is the following :

```
[...]
oldCertificate.PrivateKey.Delete();
userCertificateStore.Remove(oldCertificate);
[...]
```

With oldCertificate being a Capicom Certificate object, and userCertificateStore a Capicom Store object.

For testing, I was previously using a Smart Card with TPM and key storage as a fake VSC, on a Windows 8.1 touch pad and Gemalto smart card reader. Everything worked fine.

Now that I have a VSC installed on my touch pad, when I try to remove the certificate that is on my VSC, I get an error on the Windows security promt that allows me to choose a Smart Card (ie : [smart card choice](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/blog-images/a/dyz9.jpg))

When I select my VSC, it says : "The security driver require pilots that are not in the system. Please contact your administrator.".

This seems to be quite a generic error...

I tried to find documentation on X509 Store on MSDN website, as Capicom is deprecated, but couldn't get object methods or properties.

To temporary bypass this issue, I decided to set the Archived certificate attribute to true, in order to hide it from every certificate selection list and user Store. This works, but the key container still exists on the system... which can cause troubles with container limit number !

Anyone know which pilot to install or which security option would enable my javascript code to remove the key storage on the VSC ?

Or if anyone has a working exemple of certificate removal with X509 Store, it would be great ! Even a link to a complete documentation with object methods and properties.

Thanks